# CvBox2D is not recognized in emgucv 3.1

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I want to use CvBox2D type in emgucv 3.1.0.2504, but it is not recognized!

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Util;
using Emgu.Util;
using System;

        static CvBox2D GetROIRegion(XPointF p1, XPointF p2)
        {
             CvBox2D result = new CvBox2D();
             ...
            return result;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: can you see the class in the object explorer?. This might help: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/5a49eb70-6e2c-754a-8a80-caadc009de22.htm

Comment: @NicoRiff You mean in Object Browser? yes I can see the class there.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but according to version 3 [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a71ffd5e-d4ce-2242-c5d8-82c70d23139e.htm) `RotatedRect` is "Managed structure equivalent to CvBox2D". In version 2 there was a field "MCvBox2d" described in [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/5a49eb70-6e2c-754a-8a80-caadc009de22.htm) with the same description, but it is not there in version 3 anymore. Does this make sense?

Comment: by "field `MCvBox2d`" I meant struct, off course

Comment: @Ilya Luzyanin That's cool! thanks a lot. Please write it as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 2 there used to be a structure called [MCvBox2D](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.10/document/html/5a49eb70-6e2c-754a-8a80-caadc009de22.htm) which is a

> Managed structure equivalent to CvBox2D

In version 3 though this structure was renamed to [RotatedRect](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/a71ffd5e-d4ce-2242-c5d8-82c70d23139e.htm) - it has the same description and implements the same interfaces.

So you should be able to use `RotatedRect` in your code.

Comment: Have you one idea what is the equivalent of `Contour.HNext` in version 3 ? I have to count number of blobs from contours and i see here that i have to use `hnext` property: http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2964

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut, sorry mate, I don't use this myself. Try asking a separate question.